# Access 2010 SQL Query Deadend

Tags: ms-access, pivot

I need to create a database for a project. I've spent the past couple of months learning the basics in MS Access 2010 and have started to dabble in SQL for more specific queries. With that said, I have some very basic understanding and knowledge of the program's functionality.

I'm trying to create a query from a single table to display a series of calculations. I've made lot's of progress but now I'm scratching my head and have turned for some help.

```
Table: LIT_ALL

SITE  DATE    TRANSECT  CATEGORY  DISTANCE_M
PIT  6/2/2011     1        RKC      0.25
PIT  6/2/2011     1        FMA      0.58
PIT  6/2/2011     1        LHC      0.75
PIT  6/2/2011     2        FMA      0.5
PIT  6/2/2011     2        SA       0.6
PIT  6/2/2011     2        RKC      0.52
PIT  6/2/2011     2        LHC      0.6
PIT  6/2/2011     3        CCA      0.59
PIT  6/2/2011     3        LHC      0.6
PIT  6/2/2011     3        FMA      0.52
```

using this code

```
TRANSFORM Sum(DISTANCE_M) AS SumOfDISTANCE_M
SELECT SITE, DATE, [CATEGORY]
FROM LIT_ALL
GROUP BY SITE, DATE,[CATEGORY]
PIVOT TRANSECT;
```

I have a partial format for my final product

```
SITE  DATE      CATEGORY   1    2    3 
PIT   6/2/2011  CCA                  .59
PIT   6/2/2011  FMA       .58  .5    .52
PIT   6/2/2011  LHC       .75  .6    .6
PIT   6/2/2011  RKC       .25  .52    
PIT   6/2/2011  SA             .6
```

With the exception of a few dead ends, I have not been able to produce a result such as this.

```
SITE    DATE     CATEGORY   1      2      3     AVG    STD    SE
PIT    6/2/2011  CCA       0.00   0.00   34.5   11.5   19.92  6.64
PIT    6/2/2011  FMA       36.71  22.52  30.41  29.88  7.11   2.37
PIT    6/2/2011  LHC       47.47  27.03  35.09  36.53  10.30  3.43
PIT    6/2/2011  RKC       15.82  23.42  0.00   13.08  11.95  3.98
PIT    6/2/2011  SA        0.00   27.03  0.00   9.01   15.60  5.20
```

The values shown in this example are percent values. Each value in 1,2,3 field (Pivoted Transect Field) is formated via cell value in field 1,2, or 3/sumtotal(1,2, or 3 value respectively)*100. I'm also having issues removing the Null. I've used Nz function to some degree of success.. Only I was getting my AVG to not account for the newly inserted O value and throwing the AVG off. STDEV is your everyday run of the mill pop stdev. SE represents error.. which in this case is the STDEV/3(thats the total number of Transects). Thanks for any and all help to point me in the right direction.. I'm learning new tricks each day! Open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 queries one of which is your pivot. The second query is a standard select with aggregates for avg, stdev, and se. Then create a third query that joins the pivot query to the aggregate. I changed some field names just 'cause.

qryPivot

```
 TRANSFORM Sum(LIT_ALL.DISTANCE) AS SumOfDISTANCE
 SELECT LIT_ALL.SITE, LIT_ALL.dtDATE, LIT_ALL.[CATEGORY]
 FROM LIT_ALL
 GROUP BY LIT_ALL.SITE, LIT_ALL.dtDATE, LIT_ALL.[CATEGORY]
 PIVOT LIT_ALL.TRANSECT;
```

qryStats

```
 SELECT LIT_ALL.Site, LIT_ALL.dtDate, LIT_ALL.category, Avg(LIT_ALL.distance) AS Mean,
 StDev(LIT_ALL.distance) AS SD, StDev([distance])/3 AS SE
 FROM LIT_ALL
 GROUP BY LIT_ALL.Site, LIT_ALL.dtDate, LIT_ALL.category;
```

qryResult

```
SELECT qryPivot.*, qryStats.Mean, qryStats.SD, qryStats.SE
FROM qryPivot INNER JOIN qryStats ON (qryPivot.CATEGORY = qryStats.category) AND 
(qryPivot.dtDATE =   qryStats.dtDate) AND (qryPivot.SITE = qryStats.Site);
```

Because the pivot column names may not always be known I use the select *.